# output data from mysql to php mini blog on php

Tags: php, mysql

There is a database in just one column with the name of the blog that is displayed on the page site.co/blog and displays records from the database such as Title, description , date and image and displayed correctly ie displays the publication code blog.php

```
<?php require_once('inc/core.php');
$counter = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `blog`');
$counter = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$pages = intval( ($counter[0] - 1) / $conf['pp']) + 1;


if( isset($_GET['page'])) {
// Да, пользователь что-то передал
$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if ( $page > 0 && $page <= $pages ) {
    // Вычисляем с какого номера статьи надо начинать выводить
    $start = $page * $conf['pp'] - $conf['pp'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT {$start}, 
{$conf['pp']}";
}
  else {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT '. $conf['pp'];
    $page = 1;
  }
 }
 else {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT '. $conf['pp'];
  $page = 1;
 }
 $otvet = mysql_query($sql);
 ?>
 <div id="articles" class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($otvet)){
                    echo "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4\">
            <div class=\"article-summary\">
                <div class=\"article-img\"><img src=\"{$row['poster']}\" alt=\"\" /></div>
                <div class=\"article-title\"><a href=\"post?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['title']}</a></div>
                <div class=\"article-text\">{$row['desc']}
                </div>
                <div class=\"article-links row\">
                    <div class=\"col-xs-6\">
                        <div class=\"date-holder\">
                            {$row['date']}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"col-xs-6\">
                        <div class=\"readmore-holder\">
                            <a href=\"post?id={$row['id']}\" class=\"ybtn ybtn-small ybtn-accent-color-text\">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";

                }
                ?>
```

but as soon as you open the article ex. site.co/post?id=2 then instead of the selected article is displayed not the one that chose and the last article that added the code in the file post.php the same tell me how to fix it ???

```
     <?php require_once('inc/core.php');
 $counter = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `blog`');
 $counter = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
 $pages = intval( ($counter[0] - 1) / $conf['pp']) + 1;


 if( isset($_GET['page'])) {
 // Да, пользователь что-то передал
 $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
 if ( $page > 0 && $page <= $pages ) {
    // Вычисляем с какого номера статьи надо начинать выводить
    $start = $page * $conf['pp'] - $conf['pp'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT {$start}, 
 {$conf['pp']}";
 }
 else {
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT '. $conf['pp'];
    $page = 1;
 }
 }
 else {
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT '. $conf['pp'];
 $page = 1;
 }
 $otvet = mysql_query($sql);
 ?>  
 <div id="post-content" class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div id="post-body" class="row">
        <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($otvet)){
            echo "<div id=\"post-holder\" class=\"col-md-9\">
            <div id=\"post-1\" class=\"post\">
                <div class=\"post-thumbnail\">
                    <img src=\"{$row['poster']}\" class=\"post-image\" alt=\"\">
                </div>
                <h4 class=\"post-title\">{$row['title']}</h4>
                <div class=\"meta\">
                    <span class=\"view\">10 Views</span><span class=\"like\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"like-btn\">7 Like</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class=\"post-content\">
                    <p>{$row['content']}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=\"post-author\">
                <div class=\"row\">
                    <div class=\"col-sm-2\">
                        <img alt=\"\" src=\"images/team2.jpg\">
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"col-sm-10\">
                        <h3 class=\"name\">Admin</h3>
                        <p class=\"desc\">Nunc in ultricies odio. Vivamus ullamcorper convallis convallis. Mauris in urna sed metus iaculis pretium sed porttitor velit. Mauris id mauris ac leo eleifend volutpat. Aliquam porttitor orci et eleifend sagittis.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: update mysql to mysqli and also i'd advise prepared statements for your queries

Comment: from your code, it looks like you are trying to make pagination, but your question seems to be you want to grab one article in a page via GET variable and output everything about that article in that one page, is it?

Comment: I see sql injection

Comment: @SamEzedi 
exactly